# escaping bash 'test' keywork in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, reserved-words

I have a [bash script](https://gist.github.com/alonisser/6270653) that needs to run this command:

python manage.py test

But since `test` is a bash command by itself, I need to escape it somehow. but couldn't found out how.

any leads? or maybe I'm worrying for nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test` is a Bash builtin command, not a keyword or reserved word. This means Bash will only interpret it if it is the first token in a command, like

```
test blah
```

In

```
python manage.py test
```

Bash will just pass it as a parameter to `python` (that is, it will execute `python` with two parameters, `manage.py` and `test`); you don't need to escape it.

In general, Bash doesn't have reserved words in the sense of C-like languages. The only things you need to escape are whitespace (which Bash uses to separate params), and certain symbols including `$(&|;` which Bash uses for its variables and command separators.